# Create angular navigation from data

Tags: angularjs, routes

I want to create in angular a page with 2 views. One, a navigation view has a list of ~1000 objects along with some options to filter them e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="object in objects| filter:query | subset:subsetOp">
                {{objectname}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The list of objects is obtained by a REST query using an Angular resource.

When the name of an object is clicked I want to main part of the page to query for additional information about the clicked object and display it.

The catch comes from the fact that I need the detail pages to have URL's that can be shared, bookmarked etc and that I don't want to have to re-query the list of objects all the time.

I can only find examples using ng-route to completely replace the page - loosing the navigation, our ui-route which seems to involve defining a list of states in javascript

Comment: ui-router allows to have parent states, with a nested ui-view that is populated based on what the child state is. It supports what you want.

Comment: I don't understand how the concept of states is going to map to my requirements at all. Could you provide a link to example doing something similar or an explanation?

Comment: You create a parent state. The view associated to this state displays the list, and has a nexted ui-view. The nested ui-view is populated with the view of the sub-state, which displays the details of the clicked item. Going from one item to another item will only change the detail view. This list won't be reloaded. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Ok, what I was missing is the concept of url parameters, explained here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing
I have ended up with `$stateProvider
  .state('classes',{
   url: '/classes',
   templateUrl: 'partials/classes.html'
  })
  .state('classes.details',{
   url: '/:classname',
   templateUrl: 'partials/classTop.html',
   abstract: true    
  })
  .state('classes.details.class',{
   url: '',
   templateUrl: 'partials/classDetails.html',
   controller: 'classViewCtrl'
  })`